# If else condition in jQuery + append function

Tags: jquery

I have this condition:

```
$(document).on("click", "#save, .delRow, #closeAddButton", function (e) {
    if ($(this).is("#save")) {
        $($("#template").html()).appendTo("#dataTables-example");
        $(".rowValue").append($("#textValue").val()).attr("class", "rowValues");
        $(".taskValue").append($("#task").val()).attr("class", "taskValues");
        $(".ProleValue").append($("#primaryRole").val()).attr("class", "roleValues");
        var stuff = $("#secondaryRole").val();
        var result = (stuff.substr(stuff.length-2, 2) == ", ")? stuff.substr(0, stuff.length-2):stuff;
        $(".SroleValue").append(result).attr("class", "roleValues");
        $(".actions").append('<a href="#" class="edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalEdit"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i></a>' + 
                             '<a href="#" class="delRow"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a>').attr("class", "");
        /* Update Numbering */
       updateRowOrder();
       if($('#dataTables-example tbody tr').length == 2)
        {
            $('#dataTables-example tbody tr:first').find('.moveDown').show();
            $('#dataTables-example tbody tr:last').find('.moveUp').show();
        }
       else if ($('#dataTables-example tbody tr').length > 2)
       {
            $('#dataTables-example tbody tr:first').find('.moveDown').show();
            $('#dataTables-example tbody tr').find('.moveUpDown').show();
            $('#dataTables-example tbody tr:last').find('.moveUp').show();
       }
       else {

       }
    }
});
```

});

This is my HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTables-example">
                                <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Order</td>
                                            <td>Activity</td>
                                            <td>Task Code</td>
                                            <td>Primary Role Code</td>
                                            <td>Secondary Role Code</td>
                                        </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <script id="template" type="text/template">
                                    <tr class="move"> 
                                        <td class="id"></td> 
                                        <td><p class="rowValue"></p></td>
                                        <td><p class="taskValue"></p></td>
                                        <td><p class="ProleValue"></p></td>
                                        <td><p class="SroleValue"></p></td>
                                        <td><p class="actions"></p></td>
                                        <td><p class="moveUp" style="display:none;"><a href="#" class="up"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up fa-fw"></i></a></p>
                                            <p class="moveUpDown" style="display:none;">
                                                <a href="#" class="up"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up fa-fw"></i></a>
                                                <a href="#" class="down"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-fw"></i></a>
                                            </p>
                                            <p class="moveDown" style="display:none;"><a href="#" class="down"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-fw"></i></a></p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr> 
                                    </script>
                                </tbody>
                                </table>
```

If I click 'ADD' button it will append the html codes. How can I insert an if..else statement in this code if table row is only 1: it will not insert the html codes; then if has 2 table rows: for the first table row, it will insert the class 'down' and for the last table row, it will insert the class 'up'; and if has 3 table rows: for the first table row, it will insert the class 'down', the second table row, it will insert the class 'up' and 'down' and for the third table row, it will insert the class 'down'.
For the summary, there should only class 'up' for the first table row and class 'down for the last table row, if 2 or more table rows.

Comment: check the condition above, and stored the html tag in variable and passed it like append( variable )

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand your question, but can't you just count the number or rows with $(".upDown tr").length and then use standard JS if...else statement to decide which code to run depending on the number of rows? If you post a HTML snippet of what you need it would be much easier to visualise it.

Comment: I edit my code above. I work on it. But my problem is everytime I will 'ADD' how can I process again the code or recalculate so that it will find the first and last table row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#addButton').click(function(){
  var count = $('#dataTables-example tbody tr').length;
  if(count > 1)
  {
    $(#dataTables-example tbody tr:first-child).addClass( "up" ); // add class for first row
    if(count  > 2)
    {
      for(i=1;i<(count-1); i++)
      {
        $(#dataTables-example tbody tr).eq(i).addClass( "up down" ); //add class for intermediate rows
      }
    }
    $(#dataTables-example tbody tr:last-child).addClass( "down" ); // add class for last row
   }
});
```